# Find IDs of SSL Sessions created on the server side

Tags: java, security, ssl

I am creating the SSL Connections using JSSE provider, and wanted to find out how many SSL sessions are existing and their Session IDs.

I tried using `sslContext.getServerSessionContext().getIds()` but it always returns empty enumeration.

NOTE: SSL Sessions are being used because when I try to get the session using the session id that was sent in the Server Hello message the session is found. Also the session resumption is working.

But still I am not able to get all the session ids using above method.

**EDIT:**

```
SSLServerSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getServerSocketFactory();
SSLServerSocket serverSSLSocket = (SSLServerSocket) sslSocketFactory.createServerSocket(serverTlsConfiguration.getPort());

Socket socket = serverSSLSocket.accept();

sslContext.getServerSessionContext().getIds();
```

Am I missing some point here?

Comment: Works for me. Are you calling that method *in the server?* with the same SSLContext you used to create the SSLServerSocket?

Comment: @EJP yes I use the same SSLContext. As I told when I try to get the session based on the session id sent in ServerHello message it gets the session, but when I try to list the sessions it receives empty enumeration. Should I share the code?

Comment: Yes you should. I have written SSLSession managers so I know this works.

Comment: @EJP I have edited the question to include code